# Как проверить что все свойства объекта равны

Tags: javascript

Допустим, есть объект:

```
var obj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 2,
    c: 2
}
```

Как вывести `true`, если все свойства объекта равны друг другу?

Comment: Вывожу: `true`.

Comment: Как Вы попытались решить проблему?

Comment: я пробовал через цикл получать значения и push-ить их в массив  там уже проверять, но может есть другой способ?более лучший

Comment: Тогда стоит показать что именно Вы делали, чтобы мы знали что испробовано и как помочь. Обновите свой ответ.

Comment: "более лучший" способ - останавливаться на первом несовпадении

Comment: свойства могут быть только примитивами? или объектами тоже?

Answer (score 6):

Можно через [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
var obj = {
    a: 2,
    b: 2,
    c: 2
};

console.info(Object.keys(obj).every((val, i, arr) => obj[val] === obj[arr[0]]));
```

Comment: а если не на ECMA6?

Comment: @lesha310392, тогда `function(val, i, arr){return val!==arr[0];}`

Comment: @lesha310392, дерните полифилл [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) и замените стрелки на обычный `function`.

Comment: пардон, откатите правку, пожалуйста

Comment: @Igor, уже откатил своей правкой :)

Answer (score 3):

C [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) -

```js
const equalProps = object =>
  Object.values(object).every( ( value, index, array ) => value === array[0] );

const first = { a: 2, b: 2, c: 2 };
const second = { a: 2, b: 3, c: 2 };

console.log( equalProps( first ) );
console.log( equalProps( second ) );
```

Comment: Ох, это ещё в черновике, а мы знаем как легко можно слететь даже с 4-го этапа.